# Problem with the accuracy of the real-coded Genetic algorithm

Tags: mathematical-optimization, random, algorithm, code-review, precision-and-accuracy

Since there is no Genetic algorithm implemented in the Mathematica i tried to write a very simple genetic algorithm myself. The accuracy of the results depend upon rounding up the obtained parameters. Therefore, it is not very accurate(refer to the results section). Like any other GA codes it starts with initialization of the random population within the given bounds for each parameters. The population then will be evaluated. The best cost(lowest non-negative value) and population will be stored in their respective related lists. The parents were selected by Roulette Wheel Selection based on Sigma Scaling of the fitness so that parents are selected moderately over time(Costs must be non negative and zero is assumed for non-negative values). Arithmetic recombination crossover and uniform mutation method then applied to the population. This will continue till the condition is satisfied.In terms of speed the code performs fairly well. I would appreciate any involvement in improving or implementing more complicated methods in each section and for stopping criteria.

> Main functions used in this code and initialization of the necessary parameters

```
poslow[vec_, condition_] := 
 Block[{}, Position[vec, _?(# < condition &)] // Flatten
  ]

poshigh[vec_, condition_] := 
 Block[{}, Position[vec, _?(# > condition &)] // Flatten
  ]
eqpos[vec_, condition_] := 
 Block[{}, Position[vec, _?(# == condition &)] // Flatten
  ]

gen1[upper_, lower_, pop_] := 
 Block[{}, lower + (upper - lower)*RandomReal[1, pop]
  ]
RouletteWheelSelection[P_] := 
  Block[{r, c}, r = RandomReal[]; c = Accumulate[P]; 
   eqpos[c, First@Select[Flatten[Transpose[{c}]], # >= r &]]];

UniformCrossover[x1_, x2_, VarMin_, VarMax_] := 
  Block[{alpha, m1, m2, i},
   alpha = 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], Dimensions@x1] // Flatten;
   m1 = alpha*x1 + (1 - alpha)*x2; 
   m2 = alpha*x2 + (1 - alpha)*x1;
   (*arithmatic recombination*)
   Table[m1[[i]] = Max[m1[[i]], VarMin[[i]]], {i, 
     First@Dimensions@m1}];
   Table[m1[[i]] = Min[m1[[i]], VarMax[[i]]], {i, 
     First@Dimensions@m1}];
   Table[m2[[i]] = Max[m1[[i]], VarMin[[i]]], {i, 
     First@Dimensions@m1}];
   Table[m2[[i]] = Min[m1[[i]], VarMax[[i]]], {i, 
     First@Dimensions@m1}];
   (*Making sure population are not out-of-bound*)
   {m1, m2}
   ];
(*uniform crossover funption*)
F[x_, y_] := 2 x^2 + 4 x*y - 2.88;
(*required function for optimization*)
sigmaScalingCoeff = 1;
popSize = 100;
(*population size*)
numvariable = 2;
(*number of deciding parameters*)
popcro = 0.8;
(*cossover percentage*)
np = 2*Round[popcro*popSize/2];
(*number of the parents*)
status = False;
logen1 = 0;
higen1 = 10;
logen2 = 1;
higen2 = 10;
(*bounds of the population*)
pop = Reap[
    For[i = 1, i <= popSize, i++, Sow[Table[0, {i, numvariable}]]];][[
   2, 1]];

var1 = gen1[logen1, higen1, popSize];
var2 = gen1[logen2, higen2, popSize];
varmin = {logen1, logen2};
varmax = {higen1, higen2};
pop[[All, 1]] = var1;
pop[[All, 2]] = var2;
(*initialization of the population*)
status = False;
mutperc = 0.3;
(*mutation percentage*)
nm = Round[mutperc*popSize];
(*number of mutants*)
mutrate = 0.1;
(*mutation rate*)
mutation[x_, mutrate_, VarMin_, VarMax_] := 
 Block[{nVar, nmutrate, j, y, sigma},
  nVar = x // Dimensions;
  nVar = nVar[[1]];
  nmutrate = Ceiling[mutrate*nVar];
  j = RandomSample[Range[nVar], nmutrate];
  If[Length@j == 1, j = j[[1]], Unevaluated[Sequence[]]];
  sigma = 0.1*(VarMax[[j]] - VarMin[[j]]);
  y = x;
  y[[j]] = 
   x[[j]] + sigma*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Dimensions@j];
  Table[y[[i]] = Max[y[[i]], VarMin[[j]]], {i, First@Dimensions@y}];
  Table[y[[i]] = Min[y[[i]], VarMax[[j]]], {i, First@Dimensions@y}];
  y
  ]
(*mutation funption*)
gen = 1;
Maxgen = 1500;

minpost = {};
bestpops = {};
```

> Main part till condition is satisfied

```
While[gen <= Maxgen,
 (*stopping criteria*)
 fiteval = F @@@ pop;
 k = SortBy[fiteval, 1];
 costs = k;
 m = First@Select[costs, # > 0 &];
 posit = First@eqpos[fiteval, m];
 bests = pop[[posit]];
 AppendTo[minpost, m];
 AppendTo[bestpops, bests];
 If[gen == Maxgen, Break[], Unevaluated[Sequence[]]];
 (*breaking the loop when the maxiter is reached*)
 sigma = StandardDeviation[costs];
 If[sigma != 0, 
  costs = 1 + (costs - Mean[costs])/(sigmaScalingCoeff*sigma); 
  costs[[Position[costs, _?(# < 0 &)] // Flatten]] = 0, 
  costs[[1 ;; All]] = 1];
 (*Sigmascaling for moderate selection over time*)
 P = costs/Total[costs];
 (*probability*)
 i1 = Table[RouletteWheelSelection[P], {i1, np/2}] // Flatten;
 i2 = Table[RouletteWheelSelection[P], {i2, np/2}] // Flatten;
 (*deciding parent indicies from roulette wheelselection for \
crossover*)
 p1 = pop[[i1]];
 p2 = pop[[i2]];
 test = UniformCrossover[p1[[#]], p2[[#]], varmin, varmax] & /@ 
   Range@Length@i1;
 popopcro1 = test[[All, 1]];
 popopcro2 = test[[All, 2]];
 pop = Join[popopcro1, popopcro2];
 (*population after crossover*)
 indi = RandomSample[Range[Length@pop], Length@pop];
 pop = Table[
   mutation[pop[[indi[[i]]]], mutrate, varmin, varmax], {i, 
    Length@pop}];
 (*population after mutation*)
 {gen++}
 ]
```

> Results section

```
bestbound1 = Mean[bestpops[[All, 1]]];
bestbound2 = Mean[bestpops[[All, 2]]];
(*use these bounds for next iterations if the results are not \
satisfactory*)
roundup1 = Round[bestpops, 0.1];
roundup2 = Round[bestpops, 0.01];
roundup3 = Round[bestpops, 0.001];
bestofroundup1 = Select[(F @@@ roundup1), 0 <= # < 10^-12 &];
posbestofroundup1 = 
  Union@Table[
     eqpos[(F @@@ roundup1), bestofroundup1[[i]]], {i, 
      Length@bestofroundup1}] // Flatten;
ansroundup1 = 
 Union@Table[
   roundup1[[posbestofroundup1[[i]]]], {i, Length@posbestofroundup1}]

(*{{0.2, 3.5}, {0.4, 1.6}}*)
```

Comment: I can't spot a single question in this post... Is there anything with this code that **does not work**?

Comment: I can only make a a couple of suggestions which I suspect you might have in mind already: suggestion #1: try to figure out how to use genetic operators/functions that work on the whole of the population not on a chromosomal basis-that will increase performance because mathematica deals efficiently with list/matrices and functions that operate on them; look up the Listable property and consider using it. suggestion #2: consider a way to generate random numbers that is consistent with suggestion #1; work out the number of randoms you need per generation and consider generating them before-hand

Comment: also try to use suggestions #1 and #2 with Compile when applicable

Comment: I was thinking of building a GA in Mathematica myself, but found this... noticed this is almost 3 yrs old....wondering how I can scale this algo for a 4 variable optimization problem? and where can I configure the range for each variable? (cool code by the way :)